# How kubernetes delete CM from etcd

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

After removing a large amount `ConfigMap` from kubernetes, `etcd` cluster size has not decreased.

Who can tell what workflow store/remove data from etcd?

Comment: How did you tell it hasn't decreased?

Comment: Yes of course. We removed ~ 1500 ConfigMap, from release `kubernetes-helm`. But the size `etcd` has not decreased at all.

Comment: it is looks like a bug, could you create an issue on github.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues